# Bearer tokens container /manual validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token

Since bearer token is validating the incoming tokens it should have some container or at least method for this.

So is there any simple way to get on server list/array of all generated tokens? Or maybe are the some public methods that take string token and returns bool result ?

I need to :

-get number of all generated tokens per day

-check if token exists in list and what is it status

Comment: there is no by default method to get the data you want, you need to manually store the token while you are generating and check the status of the same.

Comment: I know how to implment custome token validation and save token for example in database. Bud in my case there is api wich is using default bearer validation and I just need 1-2 method with custom  validation without changin behavior in all api

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter how many methods you want, but here the point is there are no default methods that providing this data, so you need to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the token manually you can try this

```cs
private bool ValidateVideoToken(string token)
        {
            var symmetricKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("symmetricKey");
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey);
            var encryptKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("encryptKey"));//16char
            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);

            // Verification
            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                ValidAudiences = new string[]
                {
                      "Audience"
                },
                ValidIssuers = new string[]
                {
                      "Issure"
                },
                IssuerSigningKey = securityKey,
                TokenDecryptionKey = encryptKey,
                ValidIssuer = "Issure"
            };

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

           var claimsPrincipal = handler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
            if (claimsPrincipal?.Claims == null || !claimsPrincipal.Claims.Any())
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```